# Auto <p> regex - fix needed

Tags: php, html, regex

I have this function (which I found somewhere in Stackoverflow) to automatically add `<p>` tags in a string for the output.

```
function autop ($string) {

    // Define block tags
    $block_tag_list = array ('address', 'applet', 'article', 'aside', 'audio', 'blockquote', 'button', 'canvas', 'center', 'command', 'data', 'datalist', 'dd', 'del', 'details', 'dir', 'div', 'dl', 'dt', 'embed', 'fieldset', 'figcaption', 'figure', 'footer', 'form', 'frameset', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'header', 'hgroup', 'hr', 'iframe', 'ins', 'isindex', 'li', 'map', 'menu', 'nav', 'noframes', 'noscript', 'object', 'ol', 'output', 'p', 'pre', 'progress', 'section', 'script', 'summary', 'table', 'tbody', 'td', 'tfoot', 'th', 'thead', 'time', 'tr', 'track', 'ul', 'video');

    $tags = '<' . implode ('[^>]*>|<', $block_tag_list) . '[^>]*>';

$pattern = <<<PATTERN
/
(\A|\\n\\n)(?!$tags) # Start of string or two linebreaks or anything but a block tag
(.+?) # Just about anything
(\Z|\\n\\n) # End of string or two line breaks
/isex
PATTERN;

    $string = str_replace ("\r\n", "\n", $string);
    $string = str_replace ("\r\t", "", $string);
    $string = str_replace ("\n\t", "", $string);
    $string = str_replace ("\t", "", $string);
    $string = preg_replace ($pattern, "'\\1<p>' . nl2br ('\\2') . '</p>\\3'", $string);
    $string = preg_replace ($pattern, "'\\1<p>' . nl2br ('\\2') . '</p>\\3'", $string);
    $string = str_replace ('\"', "&quot;", $string);

    return $string;
}
```

Having this type of string:

```
<h1>Title</h1>

This will be wrapped in a p tag

This should be wrapped in a p tag too
```

it outputs

```
<h1>Title</h1>

<p>This will be wrapped in a p tag</p>

<p>This should be wrapped in a p tag too</p>
```

It works fine, but for one problem: it wraps HTML tags which are immediately after a `<p>` tag in other `<p>` tags, screwing the code. It does not happen if the HTML tags are after a `<h1>` or whatever other block tag.

Making the double `preg_replace` a single one solves the problem, but then if there are two paragraphs like in the example before, it only wraps the first one and not the second.

I feel it's only a small change which could just make it "tick", but I can't figure it out.

Maybe if someone had a strike of genius... :)

Comment: Rule 1) Don't use regexes on html. Rule 2) If using regexes on html, see rule #1.

Comment: For reference, autop usually refers to the Wordpress function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you will be happy with your solution all the way, but you should get what you are trying to do with this (watch the added `?=` in the 5th line):

```
$pattern = <<<PATTERN
/
(\A|\\n\\n)(?!$tags) # Start of string or two linebreaks or anything but a block tag
(.+?) # Just about anything
(?=\Z|\\n\\n) # End of string or two line breaks
/isex
PATTERN;
```

Without this the previous boundary `\Z` would consume the next `\A` and therefore this would not match anymore. And of course remove the double `preg_replace`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know it's not an elegant solution, but the back end is provided by a third party, so for this project I'm stuck with it. But... the damn thing now WORKS, thanks to you! Genius! :D

Comment: No problem. I am totally with you.