# Parse html code block

Tags: html, regex, parsing, preg-match

i have such html code block

```
 <tr>
   <td style="padding: 11px 8px 11px 15px; color: #000; width: 92px; border-bottom: solid   1px #ccd9e2;"> Name </td>
   <td style="color: #666;border-bottom: solid 1px #ccd9e2;"> Lusine Akopyan </td>
 </tr>
```

to parse name i use such code `preg_match("/Name<\/td>(.+?)<\/td>/is", $html, $match);`

but have nothing in `$match` var, waht i do wrong?

Comment: Rule 1, don't use regex to parse HTML... Rule 2, if using regex to parse HTML see rule #1 ([Apologies to Marc B for stealing this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525328/auto-p-regex-fix-needed#comment15233746_11525328))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like:

```
preg_match_all("/<td[^>]*>( Name )<\/td>/", $html, $match);
```

or

```
preg_match_all("/<td[^>]*>(.*?)<\/td>/", $html, $match);
```

to get all content within each TD element